# Как спрятать URL картинки в html коде?

Tags: php, вконтакте

Всем доброго времени суток. Не знаю как решить такую задачу.
На сайте отображаю аватары пользователей с ВК, как на своем сайте спрятать ссылку на картинку которая ведет на сайт ВК.

Сейчас выглядит так.

```
<img src="https://sun9-82.userapi.com/s/v1/ig1/oDd_HRJ1L1ZUcmwpuu0blsdfKURvK-6FX5_XcS4H7soK1-Awj4TdCtl3lz0zwCCDFWffruaf.jpg?size=200x200&quality=96&crop=92,23,288,288&ava=1" alt="">
```

А хочу сделать так:

```
<?php
    $url = 'тут полный адрес на картинку';
?>
// А Выводить вот так
<img src="/get_image.php?u=<?=$url?>">
```

Подскажите кто знает, как такое реализовать?

-----------------СПУСТЯ Х времени--------------

Поигрался и сделал так:

```
        <?php
// Файл get_image.php
        Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        $im=imageCreateFromJPEG($_GET["u"]);
        imageJPEG($im);
        ?>
    
    <img src="/tests/get_image.php?u=<?=$url?>">
```

Но так не работает, а если в самом файле get_image.php вместо $_GET["u"] указать переменную с адресом то все ок.

Как заставить работать так чтобы отсюда `/tests/get_image.php?u=<?=$url?>` передавать адрес изображения?

Comment: Скачивать на свой сайт и выводить картинку со своего сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кодируй картинку в base64 и выводи непосредственно в браузер без урл

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, HerRe_a_dataofEncodedONbase64..
```